# What is meant when 'wonder' (عجبت) is used for Allah?

Tags: tafseer, hadith-interpretation

I've seen the word **wonder** used some times for Allah(swt) like in the below Hadith

> Sahih Bukhari Hadith No. 3010
> Narrated Abu Huraira(ra): The Prophet(pbuh) said, Allah(swt) wonders at those people who will enter Paradise in chains.

also in a variation in Quran 37:12 Allah(swt) is given wonder attribute
(بَلْ عَجِبْتُ وَيَسْخَرُونَ)

I know that Allah's wonder is something that befits His majesty, but how can we explain it to a non-muslim?

Comment: We are not a support group.

Comment: i am asking for something to be explained!

Answer (score 1):

It essentially means that Allah is pleased with something, or considers it significant. Allah's 'wonder' does not mean that He is *surprised* or lacked of knowledge of it beforehand, since it is established that:

> إن تبدوا شيئا أو تخفوه فإن الله كان بكل شيء عليما
>
> Whether you reveal a thing or conceal it, indeed Allah is ever, of all things, Knowing.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:54](https://quran.com/33/54?translations=20)</sup>

---

**Ref:**

> وقد تقدم توجيه العجب في حق الله في أوائل الجهاد وأن معناه الرضا
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3315)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In Qur'an 37:12 - In this verse it is the Prophet who marvels. Because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) thought that whoever heard the Qur'aan believed, and when the polytheists began to mock him upon hearing the Qur'aan, he was surprised; and this verse was revealed.
In justifying the attribution of surprise to God, various aspects have been stated, including that God's surprise at something means denying it, and expressing a situation that deserves surprise.

https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AA_%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AC%D8%A8